# Angularjs $http not returning Calls on ng-click after 1 st call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html, express

i have a services which i use it in my landing controller.
the problem is that when the App init the $http gets called by default.
But i need to give params based on click. so i have implmented a ajax call on ng-click.

But i am getting the same data on ng-click

```
var sent = angular.module("sentAnalysis",["ngRoute"]);
var log = console.log.bind(console);





'use strict';
sent.service('Sentiments', function ($http) 
{
    var sentiments = [];
    return {
        getData: function(api,params,callback) {


            log(api);
            var cb = callback || angular.noop;
            if(sentiments.length !== 0) 
            {
                cb(sentiments);
            }else{
                $http.get(api,
                {
                    params : params

                })
                 .success(function(result) 
                    {

                    sentiments = result;
                    cb(result);
                    })
                    .error(function() {
                        cb();
                    })
            }
        }

    }
});
```

And the controller is

```
app.controller('landingCtrl',  function ($scope,$http,Sentiments,$rootScope) 
{

 $scope.clickYesterday = function()
 {

    Sentiments.getData(api,params,function(res) 
    {

    }   

 }; 


 $scope.clickTomorrow = function()
 {

    Sentiments.getData(api,params,function(res) 
    {

    }   

 };



 /*Default Http Always Executes*/
 Sentiments.getData(api,params,function(res) 
    {

    }   


}]);
```

The default always gets executed but the functions bind to ng-click does not get executed but alwsys return same JSON from server
Server is written in nodejs with express and felixge-node/mysql and moment.

the server is working but the clint end does not work on ng-click

the base route is

```
app.get('/api/sentiment',function(req,res)
{
  var sent ={};
  sent.status =false;
  if(user.isDB)
  {  

  var startDate = req.param('startDate');
  var endDate = req.param('endDate');

  var startValid  = moment(startDate).isValid();
  var endValid  = moment(endDate).isValid();
  log(startValid + " "+endValid);

  if(startValid && endValid)
  {

      var options ={};
      options.values = [];
      options.values.push(startDate);
      options.values.push(endDate);
      options.sql = 'Some Query ';
      options.timeout = 4000;



      connection.query(options,function(err, rows, fields)
      {
        if (!err)
        {
          log("Data row received For Query");
          log("Data row Length : "+rows.length);
          log("Executing Query :");
          log("StartDate : "+startDate);
          log("EndDate : "+endDate);
          log(options.sql);


            if(rows.length!=0)
            { 
            sent.status =true;
            sent.data = rows;
            }
            res.send(sent);
        }
      });

  }
  else
  {
    log("Invalid Date Format/Or Data Error");
  }

}
else
{
  log("DataBase Connection Issue");
   res.send(sent);
}



});
```

And the html is like this

```
 <div ng-click="clickYesterday()" class="btn btn-primary"><b>Yesterday</b></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the Sentiment Object in services
sentiment = [];

its assigned on startup but its not getting  re initialized thus holding the previous value and sending the same JSON data on every calls.
since the JSON sotred here is the first time the call is made. removing 
if then with sentiment  resolves this issue

Comment: It has nothing to do with angular $http service. The actual call to $http service occurs only once, because from subsequent times the condition `sentiments.length !== 0` is true and initially assigned value of `sentiments` is returned